# Transmission of data from Arduino through XBee

Tags: c, ubuntu, arduino, ros, xbee

1. Transmission of data from Arduino through [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) to another XBee (connected to a PC). Must the data be in char? So let's say the data I am interested in transmitting is a float. DO I have to convert it to char before I can transmit it over Arduino?
2. What is the transmission protocol for data over Arduino? Let's say I already have a function that converts the float into a string of characters. What is the protocol/ function that I can input this character for it to be transferred over XBee to another XBee. The Arduino I am using is [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) and the XBee I have is XBee PRO s1.
3. I understand that in C, programming float is only accurate up to 7 decimal places. So a double is always more accurate than float. But is it true that Arduino only accepts float? But I also read that float in Arduino is accurate up to many decimal places. How true is that last statement?
4. I need to transmit this information over XBee to another XBee. The receiving XBee is connected to a PC which runs on [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)/ [ROS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System). Is there any protocol for me to decode this character to get the initial float that I have at the Arduino side?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the XBee radios in "transparent serial" or "AT mode", then you just have a stream of 8-bit bytes that you're sending from one to the other.  How you interpret the data at that point is up to you.

1. The data doesn't have to be characters, since the XBee is transmitting 8-bit bytes.  Although floating point numbers are stored as a series of bytes, they may not be stored consistently across platforms (e.g., Arduino to PC).  So it's generally safer to send a series of characters ('0' to '9' with a '.' or ',' as the decimal separator).

   What's the range of values you're sending?  You could use fixed point to store the values -- a 32-bit integer can store approximately +/- 2 billion.  If you needed 8 decimal places, you could have that number represent +/- 20.00000000.
2. You're just sending a serial stream of data, just like you would be outputting data to the console for someone to read.
3. I'm not sure of the precision of Arduino floating point numbers.  Consider using fixed point if you're representing numbers in a tight range of values.
4. On the receiving end, you'll just open the serial port and get a stream of data.  Processing it will depend on how you've encoded it on the Arduino.  If you use `sprintf()` to convert a `float` or `double` to human-readable text, you can use `sscanf()` to convert it back to a float on the PC.